# How to install SaltStack on Ubuntu without root privileges?

Tags: ubuntu, salt-stack

I've looked through the documentation and only found the suggestion to use `virtualenv`, but my machine doesn't have it installed so that's not an option. I also looked through the `bootstrap-salt.sh` script and haven't found any suitable options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/development/hacking.html#installing-salt-for-development) suggests you should clone the git repository

```
$ git clone https://github.com/saltstack/salt
```

Then install Salt and it's dependencies using `pip` with the `--user` option

```
$ pip install --user pyzmq PyYAML pycrypto msgpack-python jinja2 psutil
$ pip install --user -e ./salt   # the path to the salt git clone from above
```

That way you will be able to uninstall it easily with pip's `uninstall` command.